# Reverse Class Method Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I created a simple class method to reverse a string and yet it returns to me the original? The Method that I created works outside of the class but for some reason it does not when I try to implement it.

See my code below:

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__items = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.__items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.__items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.__items[len(self.__items)-1]

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.__items) == 0

    def size(self):
        return len(self.__items)

    def reverse(self):
        if len(self.__items) <= 1:
            return self.__items

        return self.__items.reverse(self.__items[1:]) + self.__items[0]        


s=Stack()
rev=input("Enter string to reverse; ")
s.push(rev)
print(s.reverse())
```

Comment: what is reverse supposed to do?

Comment: Reverse a string. e.g Hello-----> olleH

Comment: len(self.__items) is always going to be 1 for a single string

Comment: What is `__items`? List of characters or a list of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reverse each string in `self.__items` not `self.__items` itself:

```
 def reverse(self):
        if not self.__items: # if items is empty return empty string
            return ""
        return " ".join(s[::-1] for s in self.__items)
```

`self.__items[::-1]` will reverse the list items not the string/strings inside.

If you wanted to do it without slicing:

```
   def reverse(self):
        if not self.__items:
            return ""
        out = ""
        for item in self.__items:
            temp = ""
            for i in range(len(item)-1, -1, -1):
                temp += item[i]
            out += temp
        return out
```

Or recursively:

```
def reverse(self):
    if not self.__items:
        return ""

    def recur(s):
        if not s:
            return ""
        return s[-1] + recur(s[:-1])
    return " ".join(recur(w) for w in self.__items)
```

Comment: Given that the string is always at the first position, Is there any way to exploit that? (I cannot think of one)

Comment: @BhargavRao, you could just use `self.__items[0]` because we already checked for an empty list  but iterating over will at least give the op a chance to add more strings

Comment: `"".join(reversed(s))` will work and rotating each letter would also work

Comment: I was thinkin of trying to do it by using recursion alone (as the OP tried to do it). It would be little difficult as `__item` is a class attribute . The `reverse` function does not accept params, so I cannot use `__item[0]`. Whatever you try  `[::-1]` is still the best. :)

Comment: @BhargavRao, added a recursive option

Comment: Aha ... That's cheating ... Havin a baby function ... :( ... (I was thinking of using recursive lambda funcs, but they crapped, so abandoned the idea)

Comment: They call child methods, inner methods... blah blah but baby methods sound better to me ... :)

Comment: @BhargavRao, i might start calling them baby methods too, who knows it might catch on ;)

Comment: Yeah, Bad habits catch on faster :)